# Ember.js: How to get an array of model IDs from a corresponding array of model attributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

For a Tag model that I have in Ember-Data, I have 4 records in my store:

Tags:

```
id   tag_name
1    Writing
2    Reading-Comprehension
3    Biology
4    Chemistry
```

In my code I have an array of tag_names, and I want to get a corresponding array of tag IDs. I'm having 2 problems:

1. My server is being queried even though I have these tags in my store. When I call store.find('tag', {tag_name: tag_name}), I didn't expect to need a call to the server. Here is all the code I'm using to attempt to create an array of IDs.

   ```
   var self = this;
   var tagsArray = ["Writing", "Reading-Comprehension", "Chemistry"];
   var tagIdArr = []
   tagsArray.forEach(function(tag_name) {
       return self.store.find('tag', { tag_name: tag_name }).then(function(tag) {
           tagIdArr.pushObject(tag.get('content').get('0').get('id'));
       })
   })
   return tagIdArr;
   ```
2. When I console.log the output of the above code gives me an empty array object with length 0. Clicking on the caret next to the empty array shows three key-value pairs with the correct data. But the array is empty. I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this behavior, but I'm not sure why this is. I've used code similar to the above in other places successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find hits the server, but peek does not.

```
var tagsArray = ["Writing", "Reading-Comprehension", "Chemistry"];
return this.store.peekAll('tag').filter(function(tag){
    return tagsArray.indexOf(tag) !== -1;
  }).mapBy('id');
```

See: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_reorganized-find-methods

Comment: ah, I think I need to upgrade my Ember version. I'll do that and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @kaustubhb Pre 1.13 you can do `store.all('tag')` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using a slight variation on your code. I'm still looping through the tagsArray (with forEach) and then I call `self.store.all('tag').filterProperty('tag_name', tag_name). Thanks for showing me the filter function. I'm going to try and change it so I'm using exactly what you've got.